# Copy table data to clipboard button on with select column only

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to copy only 1 Column data depending on filter search. This code copies all table data including header and I only want data on 1 column.

Added the Code provided below, and it worked, but the copy function didn't work when I clicked the button it's just spinning. Adding my html code here. I think I am missing some libraries.

```
 <script>
    /*
      *THIS FUNCTION CALL THE getData() FUNCTION IN THE Code.gs FILE,
      *AND PASS RETURNED DATA TO showData() FUNCTION
      */
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
    
      //THIS FUNCTION GENERATE THE DATA TABLE FROM THE DATA ARRAY
      function showData(dataArray)
      {
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $('#data-table').DataTable(
          {
          
            data: dataArray,
            //CHANGE THE TABLE HEADINGS BELOW TO MATCH WITH YOUR SELECTED DATA RANGE
            columns: [
              {"title":"Application"},
              {"title":"Queue"},
              {"title":"Site"},
              {"title":"Location"},
              {"title":"Distro"}
    ],
    // dom: 'Blfrtip',
    
     dom: 
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-4'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-4'f><'col-sm-12 col-md-4'B>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
      
            buttons: [
                        {
                            extend: 'copy',
                            text: 'Get Distro',
                            header: false,          // Disable export header tabla
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: [0,5]      // Select columns to be exported
                            },
                            title: null             // Disable title on exported data
                        }
                    ]
     
    
      });
        });
      }
    </script>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <!--INCLUDE REQUIRED EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT AND CSS LIBRARIES-->
      
    
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
          
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">         
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">     
         
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
                      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
                      
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>
     
    
    
        <!--Styling Starts here-->
        <style>
        body {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin: 1;
          }
    .header {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      padding: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #004879;
      color: white;
      font-size: 26px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
      
    
     /* Sticky navbar - toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed). The sticky value is not supported in IE or Edge 15 and earlier versions. However, for these versions the navbar will inherit default position */
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      top: 0;
      font-weight: bold
    }
    
    /* Style the navigation bar links */
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    
    /* Right-aligned link */
    .navbar a.right {
      float: right;
    }
    
    /* Change color on hover */
    .navbar a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    /* Active/current link */
    .navbar a.active {
      background-color: #666;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .container {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    
        <div class="header">
            <h1> <img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=viewn" width ="70"   />  IMC Application Directory</h1> </div>
        <div class="navbar"> <a href="https://.com/" target="_blank">AION </a> 
        <a href="https://.com/navpage.do" target="_blank">SERVICE NOW</a> 
      <!--  <a href="https://AKfycbyVCVfzzccLsvX_DLNs4Rp69e39xsj6zSvqoruqGHIY/dev" target="_blank">APPLICATION DICTIONARY</a> -->
        <a href="https://amazon.com" target="_blank">QUICKSIGHT</a> 
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
     
            <div class="col">
           
                <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                    <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
                </table>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
      
    <!--  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script> -->
      
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script> 
        
    
        <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
        
            <!--INCLUDE JavaScript.html FILE-->
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full example of [datatables copy button](https://datatables.net/reference/button/copy) with [export options column selector](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/columns.html):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script
                  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
                  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
                  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
      
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>
     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <table id="table_id">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>aa</td>
                    <td>bb</td>
                    <td>cc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>dd</td>
                    <td>ee</td>
                    <td>ff</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    
    
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#table_id').DataTable(   
            {           
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'copy',
                        text: 'Copy some column without headers',
                        header: false,          // Disable export header tabla
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [0,1]      // Select columns to be exported
                        },
                        title: null             // Disable title on exported data
                    }
                ]
            } 
        );
    });
</script>
```

And the output is:

```
aa  bb
dd  ee
```

Comment: I did try to add this, and I've run into a blank page. Data Table is not showing as well. How do I put it properly into the above code? Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: The code works if you copy to an html file and open in browser so... Check your datatables scripts, maybe you have to install export plugin

Comment: Thanks Dani. These codes work. Appreciate it.

Comment: @coders_key mark the answer as accepted if it's ok please

Comment: Done. Thanks man. Appreciate it. One quick question. Is there other way to expand my data tables to 100%? This doesn't seem to work for me. Table still have like 1 inch margin and I want to get rid of those.
<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered" style="width:100%">

Comment: I was able to figure this out. Never mind. Thank youuu